# Why does Ubuntu's terminal often cause glitching on progress bars

Tags: command-line, unity

Very often when using the terminal in Ubuntu I notice the terminal will tear progress bars across multiple lines. Have other users been affected by this? Is this application specific (the screenshot I've attached is caused when using the sdk-man utility) or something else like the scroll bar resizing? I would not expect the terminal to suffer these effects unless I'm resizing the window during the progress which I did not do.
[image]

Comment: This is likely an issue with graphical drivers, so edit your question and add information about your computer, in particular graphics card, and about your desktop: which desktop (standard Ubuntu desktop or another one), and whether you use Wayland or X11 (information can be found in Settings - About).